# Transform Query in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have written a VBA code in Access. But, I received syntax error in TRANSFORM statement. I would be grateful if you could help me.

```
Sub TransformX1()
    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "TRANSFORM Sum(BAR1.[TON]) AS SumOfTON" _
             & "SELECT BAR1.[MABD],Sum(BAR1.[TON]) AS [Total Of TON]" _
             & "FROM BAR1" _
             & "WHERE (((BAR1.[MABD]) < 1300) And ((BAR1.[MAGH]) < 1300) And ((BAR1.G) = 1))" _
             & "GROUP BY BAR1.[MABD]" _
             & "PIVOT BAR1.[MAGH]"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
End Sub
```

Comment: `RunSQL` is for action queries not resultset queries. Additionally, why are you not saving query in database? Stored queries are compiled to best execution plan (i.e., more efficient than VBA string queries called on the fly).

Answer (score 1):

If you examine your strSQL variable just before the RunSQL command, you'll find that you are missing a few spaces. Replace

```
"TRANSFORM Sum(BAR1.[TON]) AS SumOfTON" _
```

with

```
"TRANSFORM Sum(BAR1.[TON]) AS SumOfTON " _
```

and so on.

Comment: I have this same exact problem and it's not the spaces.  There is something different about the TRANSFORM Statement that we have to do in VBA.  Does anyone know?

Comment: If you do a `Debug.Print strSQL` after building it, what do you get?